# What is the purpose of "String[] whereArgs" in "int delete (String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)" function?

Tags: java, android, mysql, sqlite, android-sqlite

String[] whereArgs also present in update function of SQLiteDatabase class, what does it depicts?? I've read the documentation but not getting it,Please help.
Thanks in Advance !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[As the documentation says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#delete%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5b%5d%29), it's used for `?` markers in your query string. For example, you might use this:

```
SQLiteDatabase.delete("users", "user_name = ?", new String[] {"Talib"});
```

The use of parameter markers is very important for avoiding [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). For example,

```
SQLiteDatabase.delete("users", "user_name = ?", new String[] {"' OR '' = '"});
```

will not delete all rows of your table, but if you naively did

```
SQLiteDatabase.delete("users", "user_name = '" + userName + "'");
```

and `userName` was set to `"' OR '' = '"`, that would indeed nuke your whole table.

Answer (score 4):

If your `whereClause` is of the form `somecolumn=?`, the first element out of `whereArgs` will be used to replace the `?`. These are called positional parameters. The advantage of using positional parameters is that SQLite will handle quoting the string, escaping any embedded quotes, etc.